# Symfony Bootstrap Modal only showing backdrop not the modal itself

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, modal-dialog

Following this tutorial: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stimulus/modal-form#play, I'm currently developing a modal in which I will inject a symfony form in ajax. I use webpack and stimulus controller with data-action to open my modal, unfortunately it only shows the backdrop of the modal, not the modal itself. I searched for subjects on stackoverflow but I did not come to a solution. Here's my code:

The dropdown with the edit button launching the modal:

```
<div {{ stimulus_controller('modal', {formUrl: path('app_product_ora_edit', {'id': product_ora.id})}) }}>
    <button class="dropdown-item" data-action="modal#openModal">
        <i class="bi-pencil-square text-warning dropdown-item-icon">
        </i> Editer
    </button>
```

{{ include('modal/_modal.html.twig', {modalTitle: 'Éditer un produit O-RA',}) }}

The modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-modal-target="modalForm">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">{{ modalTitle }}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modalForm"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-modal-target="modalFormBody">
                {{ modalContent|default('Loading...') }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modalForm">Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The action from controller js:

```
static targets = ['modalForm', 'modalFormBody'];
static values = {
    formUrl: String,
}
async openModal(event) {
    this.modalFormBodyTarget.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    const modalForm = new Modal(this.modalFormTarget);
    modalForm.show();
    console.log(this.formUrlValue);
    this.modalFormBodyTarget.innerHTML = await $.ajax(this.formUrlValue);
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help you can provide.

Comment: why two `div`s with class modal?

Comment: Yep i just applied the corrections to my modal declaration and problem is still the same (edited the original post)

Comment: The version of Bootstrap is 5.2.2 and jquery version is 3.6.1

Comment: I tried to replicate your code on a fiddle, without ajax call and of course no symfony, it actually shows the modal contents: https://jsfiddle.net/3ymofaxL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i found the solution, my modal was declared IN the tr tag of my product list, i had to declare it outside the tr tag to make it works :

```
<tr>
                                <td class="text-center text-nowrap">{{ product_ora.id }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ product_ora.name }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ product_ora.purchasePrice }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ product_ora.cataloguePrice }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ product_ora.commitment }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-sm" id="productOraDropdDown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <span class="d-none d-sm-inline-block me-1">Actions</span>
                                                <i class="bi-chevron-down"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="productOraDropdDown" style="min-width: 13rem;">
                                                {% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') %}
                                                    <div data-loader-url-value="{{ path('app_product_ora_edit',
                                                        {'id': product_ora.id}) }}">
                                                        <button class="dropdown-item" data-action="modal#openModal">
                                                            <i class="bi-pencil-square text-warning dropdown-item-icon">
                                                            </i> Editer
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {{ include('product_ora/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {{ include('modal/_modal.html.twig', {modalTitle: 'Éditer un produit O-RA',}) }}
```

Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).